# Update jQuery function without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Is there a way where I can refresh a function's parameters even without reloading the whole page? For example, in the image shown in the url, if I change the value from the 'style' dropdown, its value will be passed to the accordion function so the accordion will automatically change its colors, without reloading the page. How can I do that? Thank you in advance.

[image]

It works fine in firefox, but on IE and Chrome, the whole page reloads, which reverts the
accordion to its default state.

here is the markup:
http://jsfiddle.net/F954M/

```
        var accordion = function(accordion,t,ease,style) {              
            var accordion = $("."+accordion), panels = accordion.children(), panelHead = panels.children("h3"), panelBody = panels.children("div");
            if (ease == undefined || ease == "" || ease == "linear") {ease = "linear";}
            //time controls
            if (t == undefined || t == "") { t = 500 ;}
                else if (t == "very fast") { t = 100; } else if (t == "fast") { t = 250; } else if (t == "medium") { t = 500; }
                else if (t == "slow") { t = 800; } else if (t == "very slow") { t = 1200; }
            //styling
            panelHead.attr('class',"").addClass("panelHead-"+style);                
            //accordion click handler
            panelHead.css({ "cursor":"pointer" }).click(function() {
                var bodyHeight = 0, panelIndex = $(this).parent().index();
                panelBody.eq(panelIndex).children("p").each(function() {
                    bodyHeight = bodyHeight + $(this).outerHeight(true);
                });
                panelBody.each(function() {
                    if( $(this).parent().index() == panelIndex && $(this).height() == 0) {
                        $(this).animate({"height":bodyHeight},t,ease);
                        }
                    else if  ( $(this).parent().index() == panelIndex && $(this).height() > 0) {
                        $(this).animate({"height":0},t,ease);
                        }
                    else { $(this).animate({"height":0},t,ease); }
                });
                console.log(t + ", " + ease + ", " + style);                    
            });
            panelBody.css({ "height":0, "overflow":"hidden"});          
        };
    $(function() {
        $("form").change(function(e) {              
            location.reload(false);
        })  
    });
```

Comment: provide the script and markup,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can try this. This active your function when you change the value of your select.

```
$(YourSelectObject).on("change", YourFunction);
```

Edit--

In your code you alredy have the change function. Just remove location.reload(false) and add accordion("accordion", $("#speed").val(), $("#easing").val(), $("#style").val()). And it works.

```
$("form").change(function(e) {

//location.reload(false);           
accordion("accordion", $("#speed").val(), $("#easing").val(), $("#style").val());
});

accordion("accordion", $("#speed").val(), $("#easing").val(), $("#style").val());
```

Comment: I am actually using that code, but the concern is the
$("form").change(function() {
   location.reload(false);
   accordion(newParameters);
});

Comment: Remove location.reload(false). In your code the accordion(newParameters); is out of the change function. Take care of that.

Comment: I've just done that and it works only for one of the parameters. The other parameters are not being updated.

Comment: on the last parameter is updated, but the others are not.

Comment: the problem is that your "accordion click handler" is adding click events and is only taking the first one or maybe all at the same time, that is confusing. Sorry at this moment I don't know how to solve that :(